# Obtener la ubicacion de un archivo seleccionado con OpenFileDialog en c#

Tags: c#

buen día necesito obtener la ubicacion de un archivo seleccionado con OpenFileDialog en c# y poner esa ubicacion en una variable string, agradecere su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OpenFileDialog choofdlog = new OpenFileDialog();
choofdlog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
choofdlog.FilterIndex = 1;
choofdlog.Multiselect = true;

if (choofdlog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)    
{     
    string sFileName = choofdlog.FileName; 
}
```

Tomado de [How to get file path from OpenFileDialog and FolderBrowserDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449988/how-to-get-file-path-from-openfiledialog-and-folderbrowserdialog)

Comment: gracias me funcionó :)

Comment: y como se establece el tipo de archivos que busca el OpenFileDialog?

Comment: Por ejemplo si solo quieres establecer archivos de office sería así: `choofdlog.Filter = "Office Files|*.doc;*.xls;*.ppt";`